# Liferay 7: Error when trying to activate a bundle portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I´m trying to install a bundle into Liferay 7. When I upload the jar into App Manager the module only was installed, then when I tried to activate throws an exception:

```
2018-09-04 17:25:24.739 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-4][PortletServlet:112] javax.portlet.PortletException: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.ctliv.vportlet [998]_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception; version="7.4.0"_ [Sanitized]
    javax.portlet.PortletException: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.ctliv.vportlet [998]_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception; version="7.4.0"_ [Sanitized]
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.callActionMethod(LiferayPortlet.java:207)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.callActionMethod(MVCPortlet.java:418)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.processAction(LiferayPortlet.java:97)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.processAction(MVCPortlet.java:260)
        at com.liferay.marketplace.app.manager.web.internal.portlet.MarketplaceAppManagerPortlet.processAction(MarketplaceAppManagerPortlet.java:216)
        at com.liferay.portlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:77)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:50)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:108)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:153)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ResponseStateHandler.processRequest(ResponseStateHandler.java:62)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.DispatchTargets.doDispatch(DispatchTargets.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portlet.internal.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:606)
        at com.liferay.portlet.internal.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:652)
        at com.liferay.portlet.internal.InvokerPortletImpl.processAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:341)
        at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.portlet.MonitoringInvokerPortlet.processAction(MonitoringInvokerPortlet.java:208)
        at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl._processAction(PortletContainerImpl.java:485)
        at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl.lambda$processAction$0(PortletContainerImpl.java:144)
        at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl._preserveGroupIds(PortletContainerImpl.java:390)
        at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl.processAction(PortletContainerImpl.java:137)
 ...                

        Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.ctliv.vportlet [998]_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception; version="7.4.0"_ [Sanitized]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:429)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:402)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:421)
        at com.liferay.marketplace.app.manager.web.internal.portlet.MarketplaceAppManagerPortlet.activateBundles(MarketplaceAppManagerPortlet.java:127)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.callActionMethod(LiferayPortlet.java:189)
        ... 150 more
```

My pom.xml looks like:

```
<import.package>
            !com.google.gwt.*,
            !elemental.events,
            !com.vaadin.client.*,
            com.vaadin*;resolution:=optional;version="[8.1,9)",
            org.osgi.framework;version="[1.8,2)",       
            com.liferay.counter.kernel.service;version="1.0.1",
            com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception;version="[7.0,8)",
            com.liferay.portal.kernel.log;version="7.0.0",
            com.liferay.portal.kernel.model;version="2.0.0",
            com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet;version="8.0.0",
            com.liferay.portal.kernel.service;version="1.34.0",
            com.liferay.portal.kernel.util; version="8.4.0",
            javax.portlet*;version="[2.0,3)",
            javax.sql,
            javax.management,
            org.xml.sax,
        </import.package>
        <export.package>
            com.github.ctliv.vportlet.export;version="${project.version}",
            com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception;version="[7.0,8)"
        </export.package>
    </properties>

<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <manifestLocation>META-INF</manifestLocation>
                        <Bundle-Name>${project.name}</Bundle-Name>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                        <Import-Package>${import.package}</Import-Package>
                        <Export-Package>${export.package}</Export-Package>
                        <Bundle-Activator>${bundle.activator}</Bundle-Activator>
                        <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
                        <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                        <Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment>JavaSE-1.8</Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Seems that I have to include the com.liferay.portal.kernel dependency into my jar?
I included into Export package but didn't work

Comment: No, you should not include it! My first bet here is that the bundle was built to a different version of Liferay. Where did you get this bundle?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to include the kernel package as needed imports

Comment: You are right, its a liferay7.1 and vaadin 8.5.1 issue. After I removed the import kernel package and deploy the module I have ClassNotFound exception from portal.kernel classes. So I decided to keep Liferay 7.0 and vaadin 8.5.1, the module is deployed and activated correctly

Comment: @IMA if it solved your issue, you could post it as an answer to your question! It makes life easier for future readers.

Comment: the exceptions already states the issue .. "Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception; version="7.4.0"" .. the version for 7.0  is 2.x and for 7.1 is 3.x ...